# Colored boxes on around the folder name in terminal

Tags: command-line, permissions

I gave local user to read and write permission to a particular folder using command

```
       chmod 777 /data/folder/
```

Now I am seeing a colored box hovering the folder's name which I really bugging me.Is there any way I can remove it ?
I can't attach the image because I don't have reputation of 10.

Comment: Please put a link to the image.

Answer (score -1):

`chmod 777` sets permissions so that the owner, group and others can read, write and execute. The highlighting is shown if others can write to it. If you don't need that, just `chmod o-w /data/folder`. Also, if you are the only one who needs to use the folder, I would suggest `700` or `755`.

Comment: That command is to take off the permission, I want to take off the highlighting. Is that possible ?

Comment: That's all true, but the problem is this answer is not really a good answer, should one rely on the possibility of removing permissions in order to remove the highlighting? This is somehow useful, hence I'm not downvoting it, but I think it fits better as comment

Comment: It's highlighted because it is actually something to be concerned about. So, instead of trying to remove a safety feature, I would be concerned about what you're actually letting people do.

Comment: The highlighting is a good thing, and if it bothers you, you can always just use ls without color. Big noisy warnings for dangerous situations are also good :)